# Configuration issue with stateMachine and it's version

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-statemachine

```
@Service
public class ClaimService {
    @Autowired
    ClaimRepository claimRepository;
    @Autowired
    StateMachineFactory factory;
    public boolean selectDate(ClaimRequest claimRequest) {
        StateMachine<ClaimStates, ClaimEvents> sm = build(claimRequest.getId());
        Message<ClaimEvents> addDate = MessageBuilder.withPayload(ClaimEvents.SELECTDATE)
            .setHeader("claimId", claimRequest.getId()).build();
        return sm.sendEvent(ClaimEvents.SELECTDATE);
    }
    private StateMachine<ClaimStates, ClaimEvents> build(Long claimId) {
        Claims claims = claimRepository.findById(claimId).get();
        String claimIdKey = Long.toString(claims.getId());
        StateMachine<ClaimStates, ClaimEvents> sm = factory.getStateMachine(claimIdKey);
        sm.stop();
        sm.getStateMachineAccessor().doWithAllRegions(sma -> {
        sma.addStateMachineInterceptor(new StateMachineInterceptorAdapter<ClaimStates, ClaimEvents>() {
            //                @Override
            public void preStateChange(State<ClaimStates, ClaimEvents> state, Message<ClaimEvents> message, Transition<ClaimStates, ClaimEvents> transition, StateMachine<ClaimStates, ClaimEvents> stateMachine) {
                Optional.ofNullable(message).ifPresent(msg -> {
                    Long claimId = Long.class.cast(msg.getHeaders().getOrDefault("claimId", -1));
                    Claims claims = claimRepository.findById(claimId).get();
                    claims.setClaimState(state.getId().name());
                    claimRepository.save(claims);
                });
            }
        });
        sma.resetStateMachine(new DefaultStateMachineContext<ClaimStates, ClaimEvents>(
                ClaimStates.valueOf(claims.getClaimState()), null, null, null));
    });
    sm.start();
    return sm;
    }
}
```

Here I am trying the persist State of Application using StateMachine. But when I am working on it is gives issues with its configuration and it's version.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'stateMachine': Invocation of init method failed; nested exc
```

full logs:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This object has already been built
at org.springframework.statemachine.config.common.annotation.AbstractAnnotationBuilder.build(AbstractAnnotationBuilder.java:43) ~[spring-statemachine-core-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.statemachine.config.builders.StateMachineConfigBuilder.performBuild(StateMachineConfigBuilder.java:46) ~[spring-statemachine-core-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.statemachine.config.builders.StateMachineConfigBuilder.performBuild(StateMachineConfigBuilder.java:34) ~[spring-statemachine-core-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.statemachine.config.common.annotation.AbstractConfiguredAnnotationBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredAnnotationBuilder.java:112) ~[spring-statemachine-core-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.statemachine.config.common.annotation.AbstractAnnotationBuilder.build(AbstractAnnotationBuilder.java:40) ~[spring-statemachine-core-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.statemachine.config.common.annotation.AbstractConfiguredAnnotationBuilder.getOrBuild(AbstractConfiguredAnnotationBuilder.java:129) ~[spring-statemachine-core-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.statemachine.config.configuration.StateMachineConfiguration$StateMachineDelegatingFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(StateMachineConfiguration.java:170) ~[spring-statemachine-core-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:920) ~[spring-context-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731) ~[spring-boot-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
at com.example.springstatemachinechatgpt.SpringstatemachinechatgptApplication.main(SpringstatemachinechatgptApplication.java:18) ~[classes/:na]

2023-06-26 10:45:48.225  WARN 24556 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'stateMachine': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.statemachine.config.StateMachineConfig.getTransitions()" because "stateMachineConfig" is null
2023-06-26 10:45:48.227  INFO 24556 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-06-26 10:45:48.238  INFO 24556 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2023-06-26 10:45:48.275  INFO 24556 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2023-06-26 10:45:48.281  INFO 24556 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2023-06-26 10:45:48.320  INFO 24556 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-06-26 10:45:48.377 ERROR 24556 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'stateMachine': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.statemachine.config.StateMachineConfig.getTransitions()" because "stateMachineConfig" is null
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:920) ~[spring-context-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731) ~[spring-boot-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.7.12.jar:2.7.12]
at com.example.springstatemachinechatgpt.SpringstatemachinechatgptApplication.main(SpringstatemachinechatgptApplication.java:18) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.statemachine.config.StateMachineConfig.getTransitions()" because "stateMachineConfig" is null
at org.springframework.statemachine.config.configuration.StateMachineConfiguration$StateMachineDelegatingFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(StateMachineConfiguration.java:171) ~[spring-statemachine-core-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.27.jar:5.3.27]
... 16 common frames omitted

Comment: hi there can you share the full logs

Comment: Please add the full stack trace of the exception to your question.

Comment: Please add the full stack trace of the *BeanCreationException*!

Comment: added the full logs

Comment: The problem occurs when creating a bean named `stateMachine`, not `claimService`.

Comment: I have claimservice. I don't have any bean with stateMachine and  I think a problem with these two lines .
@Autowired
StateMachineFactory factory;
StateMachine<ClaimStates, ClaimEvents> sm = factory.getStateMachine(claimIdKey);  
Can you help me how to resolve this?

Comment: Why do you think that? Have you read the stack trace? How do you explain `claimService` not appearing?

Comment: Have you seen this in stack trace    main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'stateMachine': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.statemachine.config.StateMachineConfig.getTransitions()" because "stateMachineConfig" is null.     But if you see no where I am using configration bean inside Service.

Comment: For your refrence this is my Config file

Comment: The problem occurs when creating a bean named stateMachine, not claimService

Comment: Yes, But not able to create it properly can you help me with any reference do you have?

Comment: Finally, I resolved this issue, it is at the configuration level. I am using two annotations EnableStateMachine and EnableStateMachineFactory. Because Of this, it is building stateMachine object twice. If you want to enable EnableStateMachineFactory Please remove EnableStateMachine Annotation. Only one annotation is needed.